# createState mathod is not working in StatefulWidget in flutter.... it shows the following error

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-method-channel

there createState mehod is not working..

```
[class MysignupPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MysignupPage({ Key key }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _MysignupPageState createState() => _MysignupPageState();
}
class _MysignupPageState extends StatelessWidget {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;][1]
```

this error is shown
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/An0iV.png

Comment: Try to post the error details as text and not as an image. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Also, have you read the first line on the error trace? your method return type doesn't match with whatever actually you return.